# как решить проблемку Class 'GridView' not found?

Tags: yii2

new.php

```
<div class="history-balance-index">

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            ['attribute' => 'user_id',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->user->username;
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'balance',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->balance . '<br>
                        <span class="text-success">' . $model->credit . '</span>';
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'balance_up',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return Html::tag('span', $model->balance_up . '<br>' . $model->credit_up . (($model->credit_up >= 0)), [
                        'class' => ($model->credit_up >= 0) ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            [
                'attribute' => 'type',
                'filter' => Html::activeDropDownList(
                    $searchModel,
                    'type',
                    HistoryBalance::getSortLabels(),
                    [
                        'everyday' => 'каждый день',
                        'class' =>
                            'form-control form-control-sm'
                    ]
                ),
            ],
            'comment',
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

index.php

```
<?php

use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel backend\models\HistoryBalanceSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'History Balances');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<?= $this->render('new') ?>
```

Comment: Модуль точно установлен?
Попробуйте посмотреть тут https://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=48200

Comment: "kartik-v/yii2-widget-switchinput": "*"

Answer (score 1):

В начале файла new.php добавьте строки:

```
use common\models\HistoryBalance;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
```

То есть подключать классы нужно именно в том файле, в котором Вы их используете. А в index.php эти строки можно убрать - такие классы не используются в данном файле.

Также нужно заменить $this->render(...) на $this->renderPartial(...) и передать в него параметры:

```
$this->renderPartial('new', [
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 
    'searchModel' => $searchModel
]);
```